# Bash script using negative to cycle through

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a bash script that includes a nested for loop within which a variable should cycle through negative exponents, viz:

```
for ABPOW in {-11..-9}
do
ABC = $((10**$ABPOW))
          for ABCOEFF in {1..9}
          do
              sed -e 's/ACOEFF/'$ABC'/'\
```

This is only the inner two for loops of the code. When the values in the first bracket (for ABPOW) are positive, the code runs fine. However, when I have them as i do above, which is what I need, the error communicated to screen is:

```
./scripting_test2.bash: line 30: 10**-11: exponent less than 0 (error token is "1")
```

How do I make this run? Thanks in advance.

PS: I tried putting a negative sign in front of `$ABPOW` but the exponents are still recorded as positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash does not support floating point arithmetic (which is necessary for raising something into a negative power). Instead, you should use the `bc` utility.

```
ABC=$(bc -l <<< "10 ^($ABPOW)")
```

Also, there should be no spaces before and after the `=` in variable assignments

Comment: Thanks user000001. In the file where these values are being saved, i'm getting the correct value after using the code you advised above, but it is in the form:   abundance  = 4*.00000000001000000000;        All the extra zeros after the position of the 1 don't make sense?

Comment: @stars83clouds Not really possible to remove the trailing zeros with `bc` AFAIK. But you can use `awk`, for example like: `ABC=$(awk '{print 10^$1}'<<< "$ABPOW")`

Answer (score 1):

Bash doesn't support floating point data types.

```
$ man bash|grep -c -i float
0
```

Do you have `python` installed?

```
ABC=$( python -c "print 10**$ABPOW" )
```

Comment: Yes, python is installed. A question though, can I alter the line in the bash script so that it calls python to carry out the above? Or would I have to rewrite the script in python?

Comment: You can alter it as I've shown in this answer.  The `ABC=` line is what you could use instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

`perl -e 'for $abpow (-11..-9) { $abc=10**$abpow; for (1..9) { system("echo $abc"); } }'`

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use awk for your complete script that has full support for floating point arithmetic:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=-11; i<=-9; i++) {ABC=10^i; print ABC}}'
1e-11
1e-10
1e-09
```